# angularjs 1.6.x oauth redirect url with param not fired $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, route-provider

I am implementing oauth2 login with AngularJS 1.6.x

My index.html is located at my domain eg. http://mydomain/app/

When user click a button on the page, it will redirect the user to a oauth page for login using below code snippet

```
window.location.replace("https://xxxx/oauth2/xxx");
```

The user will then be redirected to my app again at http://mydomain/app/?code=xxxxx

The problem I am encountering is that the `when('/:code', {` is not triggered and the loginCtrl is not fired in which I would like to capture the oauth authorization code. Anything I have done wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Below is my app.js file

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

// Routing
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
              templateUrl : 'pages/main.html',
              controller  : 'mainCtrl'
            })

            .when('/:code', {
              templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
              controller  : 'loginCtrl'
            })

    });
```

Comment: Try to use $location.path('url') to navigate to new page on button click. Create the desired url with the code parameter. You have not mentioned from where and how the value of parameter code is coming?

Comment: Thanks for your help, as user will be directed to the resource server like facebook for oauth login, so they are out of my app and $location.path is not applicable. And the code is return from the resource server.